# haproxy server dropping a lot of connections

Tags: linux, high-availability, haproxy

I am running a haproxy server , that serves a particular traffic and the customers continue to report the connections get dropped from their end. Not sure what could be causing this.

My sysctl.conf looks as below.

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65023
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 10240
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 400000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 60000
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 3
net.core.somaxconn = 10000
```

ulimit -n returns 65535 as well.

My /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg looks as below

```
global
  maxconn 50000 # Max simultaneous connections from an upstream server
  spread-checks 5 # Distribute health checks with some randomness
  log /dev/log  local0
  log /dev/log  local1 notice
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon


defaults # Apply to all services
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  maxconn 25000
  balance roundrobin
  option abortonclose # abort request if client closes output channel while waiting
  option httpclose # add "Connection:close" header if it is missing
  option forwardfor # insert x-forwarded-for header 
  option redispatch # any server can handle any session
  retries 3
  timeout client 60s
  timeout connect 30s
  timeout server 30s
  timeout check 30s
  timeout http-request 6s
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats # Real path redacted
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats auth root:*******! # Real credentials redacted
  #monitor-uri /monitor # Returns 200 if we're up; real path redacted
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http

frontend incoming *:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    monitor-uri /haproxy_test
    default_backend my_app


backend my_app
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk /api/health
    server my_server_A 0.1.2.3:80 check inter 5000 fastinter 1000 fall 3 rise 1 weight 1 maxconn 5000
    server my_server_B 4.5.6.7:80 check inter 5000 fastinter 1000 fall 3 rise 1 weight 1   maxconn 5000
```

What could be the setting that can lead to connections dropping from the other side.  Most of the reported dropouts were from the Dublin, Ireland and the servers are in West US, if  that helps.